# Properly shutdown a fiber based job system

Tags: c, multithreading, jobs, fibers

I have difficulties to properly shut down a job system I implemented.
Currently I have a main thread posting jobs in a loop and worker threads executing jobs in a loop :

```
void thread_proc(void *param)
{
    Job job;
    while(running)
    {
        job = QUEUE_POP(job_queue);  //this call is blocking : if no job is found in the queue, put the tread to sleep
        job.work(self, job.param);
    }
}
```

Obviously the code is simplified, but I don't think the missing code is relevant to the issue.

Now, when the user wants to quit the program, running is set to false, but if no jobs are left in the queue, worker threads block indefinitely in the QUEUE_POP function.

The only solution I found is to push enough dumb jobs to the queue so that all threads are waked up, and come out of the while loop because running is false. 
It really seems like a dirty fix to me, so is there any standard or better way to do this ?

Comment: If you have a main thread and worker threads; then it doesn't sound like you are using fibers at all. Did you mean "Currently I have a single thread being shared by M fibers (a main fiber and some worker fibers)" or "Currently I have a pool of N threads being shared by M fibers"? For the former, you can wait until the job queue is empty and free any resources that were used by fibers to return to a "single thread only" system. For the latter, if jobs are done in FIFO order you could create M "terminate your fiber" jobs (with no need for `running` flag, where fiber frees its own resources)..

Comment: I have a pool of N threads being shared by M fibers. I do not think sending M jobs (M is in the order of magnitude of 128) is very efficient compared to sending 8 jobs to shutdown thread, especially because I have no need to clean fiber resources per fiber, I can free everything in one free call. But I will try it, maybe the performance impact is negligible